# How can I connect to an external database from a sql statement or a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, linked-server

When running a SQL statement or a stored procedure on a database, can you connect to an external database and pull data from there?

something like:

```
SELECT a.UserID, b.DataIWantToGet 
  FROM mydb.Users as a, externaldb.Data as b
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to [setup a Linked Server instance](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3085211/Linked-Servers-on-MS-SQL-Part-1.htm).  Then you can reference the external database as though it were a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 4):

Yep -- there's two methods: either use the function `OPENROWSET`, or use linked servers. OPENROWSET is useful for ad-hoc single statements, but if you're going to be doing this regularly, read up on linked servers as they allow you to do exactly what you've specified in your SQL Statement ... e.g.,

> `SELECT database.owner.table` for local data
>  
>   `SELECT server.database.owner.table` for remote data

And yes, you can mix and match to do joins twixt local and remote. Note though that you'll need to be caureul if you do joins against large tables that exist on the remote server as the query could take a long time to exexute...

Comment: I presume OPENROWSET will work well, so long as it's allowed. I keep getting this error, "SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server."

Comment: See MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/ad-hoc-distributed-queries-server-configuration-option

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.  You should take a look at [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) for starters.  You can also use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to hit them directly with no linked server.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way :

- Click connect to server
- when it asks for server name use:
  **192.168.X.X,1433\SQLEXPRESS** insted of *YOURPC\SQLEXPRESS*

> (The ip and opened port of target sql server)

- Type correct username and password
- Done!