# SQL Server pulling data from different server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, linked-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I connect to an external database from a sql statement or a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942228/how-can-i-connect-to-an-external-database-from-a-sql-statement-or-a-stored-proced)

I have a database server 'A'(SQL Server 2008) and database server 'B' (SQL Server 2005).

I need to pull some data  from a database on server 'B' when I am on server 'A'.

I tried this query on Server 'A':

```
SELECT *
FROM  [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[TableName]
```

I am getting this error :

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Is there some thing wrong with my query or do we need to change any setting on the server
so that I will be able to access the database.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query, you need to configure the linked server with appropriate credentials to use to connect to the remote server. You can find the linked server properties in Management Studio > Object Explorer > Server A > Server Objects > Linked Server > B (right-click and hit properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might still need to add a login for the linked server...

```
exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin ‘LinkedServer’, 'true'
```

This will cause your 'A' server to try to impersonate your login on server B.

There's more detailed info / reference here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/08/10/694657.aspx